# Custom Wordpress XML import to Post

Tags: xml, wordpress

I've been looking and looking but have had no such luck. What I'm trying to do is take generated XML file from a third party site and upload it to Wordpress, and have Wordpress import each entry in the XML file as a post with custom definitions..

i.e. the title would be the title, the description would be the description, the category would be the tag, etc..

Any suggestions, point me in the right direction? Again I'm looking to import a custom xml feed with many entries and have them imported as separate posts.

Comment: Please close this, I am not able to provide an answer as it's much much too detailed and this question is from 2 YEARS ago.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there exists a 3rd party commercial plugin that can do this.

WP All Import (http://www.wpallimport.com can import XML files in any format. You use a drag & drop interface to assign the fields in your XML file to your post content and Custom Fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the wp dashboard then tools then import and then there is an option for importing posts.  As long as your XML file is the same format as the uploader uses then it should work fine.

Comment: Check the Wordpress Codex for importing content, not sure if there's blogware or a converter since I've never done it, : http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content

Answer (score 0):

A custom import is going to take a custom solution.  Your best bet is to take a wordpress generated xml document and make an excel template out of it, then import the data that way.  Here is a link to get you started, or at least give you the idea.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg469857.aspx  There are plenty of other ways to do this,  here is another way you could try.  http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_template.asp